# How do I get trac 12.2 to work on RHEL5's httpd with CollabNet SVN 1.6.17 (which has its own httpd)?

Tags: svn, rhel5, trac, collabnet

I installed CollabNetSubversion-client-1.6.17-1.x86_64.rpm, which installs httpd v2.2.19

```
# /opt/CollabNet_Edge/csvn/bin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.19 (Unix)
```

I installed Trac-0.12.2.tar.gz.

On the Apache httpd that comes with RHEL5, which is running v2.2.3

```
# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
```

I installed mod_wsgi, since that is what the trac website recommended.

python.conf settings for the 2.2.3 httpd:

```
Alias /trac/chrome/common /var/trac/htdocs/common
Alias /trac/chrome/site /var/trac/htdocs/site
<Directory "/var/trac/htdocs">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias /trac /var/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
<Directory /var/trac/cgi-bin>
  SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
<LocationMatch "/trac/[^/]+/login">
  AuthType Digest
  AuthName "trac"
  AuthDigestDomain /trac
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/trac.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

I setup a trac project and configured it to point to an existing SVN repository.

The first error reported in trac.log was:

```
ImportError: No module named svn
```

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion#Troubleshooting has the answer, so I added symbolic links to the bindings that are in the CollabNet area:

```
cd /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages
ln -s /opt/CollabNet_Edge/csvn/lib/svn-python/libsvn .
ln -s /opt/CollabNet_Edge/csvn/lib/svn-python/svn .
```

Next error in trac.log (thanks for reading this far -- this is the real problem):

```
Trac[svn_fs] INFO: Failed to load Subversion bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/versioncontrol/svn_fs.py", line 267, in    __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/versioncontrol/svn_fs.py", line 68, in _import_svn
  File "/opt/CollabNet_Edge/csvn/lib/svn-python/svn/fs.py", line 19, in ?
     from libsvn.fs import *
  File "/opt/CollabNet_Edge/csvn/lib/svn-python/libsvn/fs.py", line 7, in ?
     import _fs
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/libsvn/../../../lib/libsvn_subr-1.so.0:
  undefined symbol: apr_memcache_add_server
```

I found this page that speaks of the same problem: http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=313639

The advice given: "you probably need to use our Apache server or update yours to 2.2.11" (i.e., 2.2.19 to match the one in the CollabNet package).  Well, the CollabNet-bundled httpd server doesn't have mod_wsgi installed, and I'm not sure how I could build such and add it to their server -- so I don't like that option.  I'd rather not update our main httpd from 2.2.3 to 2.2.19 -- but is this really my only other option?

BTW, I tried downloading SVN 1.6.17 and building and installing swig-py -- to build the bindings, hoping to use them with the 2.2.3 httpd and trac.  However, I'm not sure this is safe/correct... SVN is tied to the 2.2.19 httpd, somehow, right?  Anyway, I couldn't get that to work either.  Any advice appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Following Graham's suggestion, I compiled a 2.2.19 httpd server (to replace the RH5 2.2.3 httpd) and now everything is working.  My first attempt with the 2.2.19 httpd failed.  I had to configure httpd with option `--with-included-apr`, then everything worked.

Comment: Can you please phrase this as a question?

Comment: Sure, good point.  The real question is how can I get trac to run on the RHEL5 httpd when CollabNet SVN is running on its own separate httpd, with a different version of httpd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binaries you are using were built against a newer Apache version and specifically a newer version of the APR libraries than your Apache 2.2.3 installation you are using. There is no way around the problem except for upgrading to Apache version which uses a new enough APR library.

Comment: Thanks Graham.  I started down this road near the end of the work day earlier today, but it is good to hear that I'm finally going down the right road now.